# Difference between %CHECK() and %checkr() in RPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, difference, rpgle

I visited many sites but could not get any satisfactory answer. Please, help me to understand this one. I tried to make a program but could not understand. 
I tried:

```
 String  = 'AABC1ABD2AB3A';                         

 Pos = %check ('ABCD' : %trim(String));             
 dsply pos;
```

Comment: Check out this article by John Paris: http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg022509-story01.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by `I tried to make a program but could not understand.`

You don't say what is wrong with the example code, so we can't help much. The code that you show looks fine, although it doesn't show the definitions for `String` and for `pos`, nor does it show how the program will end.

Here is a more complete example:

```
 D string          S             15

 D pos1            S             10  0 inz( 0 )
 D pos2            S             10  0 inz( 0 )

  /free

     String = 'AABC1ABD2AB3A' ;
     //            ^      ^
     // The above characters will trigger mismatches for
     // %CHECK() and %CHECKR.

     Pos1 = %check ( 'ABCD' : %trim( String )) ;
     Pos2 = %checkr( 'ABCD' : %trim( String )) ;

     // Will display the value "1 3"
     dsply ( %subst( %trim(String): pos1: 1 ) + ' ' +
             %subst( %trim(String): pos2: 1 ) );

    *inlr = *on ;
    return ;

  /end-free
```

The value in `String` is checked first from the left with %CHECK() and then from the right with %CHECKR(). The value is trimmed with %TRIM() to avoid getting hits on any leading or trailing blanks. Then the tests look for any characters that don't match the supplied test characters `ABCD`. The program tries to make sure that `String` only contains the test characters, and it marks the positions of the first characters that fail the tests.

The indexes of the failing characters are stored in `Pos1` and `Pos2`. (If all characters pass the checks, a zero will be returned.)

The DSPLY op-code will output the first characters that don't match. It uses the index values to pull single-character substrings for the failing characters. It shows different characters for %CHECK() and %CHECKR() because they start at different ends of the `String`.

Answer (score 2):

%check() parses left to right, %checkr() parses right to left.

Given the example, %check() will return 5 and %checkr() will return 12.